# Occupy the total height and width of the classes in all images

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

#### Problem:

I created an image slider, however my problem is that I cannot fill the width and total height (100%) of the drop and abc classes.

#### Question:

How can I make all images occupy their entire area, without losing their quality?

**code**

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="overflow-y: auto;">
    <div class="drosp">
        <div class="c">
                <ng-template>
                    <ngb-carousel id="carousel" #carouse *ngIf="imagens" >
                        <ng-template *ngFor="let imgIdx of imagens; let i = index" [id]="i" ngbSlide>
                            <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
                                <img [src]="imgIdx.Imagem" class="img-responsive">
                                </div>
                            </ng-template>
                        </ngb-carousel>
                    </ng-template>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Try to add the background-image instead of <img src"">..

Comment: Instead of using an `<img...>` you should go for adding e.g. a full width/height `<div>`element and apply the css settings `background-image`along with `background-size` set to `cover`.

Comment: Do you tied `object-fit: cover` property on img?

Comment: @newBee 
What do you mean, can you help me?

Comment: @StasAmasev This didn't work on all images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add these styles:

```
ngb-carousel,
:host ::ng-deep ngb-carousel .carousel-inner,
:host ::ng-deep ngb-carousel .carousel-item,
:host ::ng-deep ngb-carousel .picsum-img-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.img-responsive {
  obejct-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Can youy try to change:

```
<img class="img-responsive" [src]="imgIdx.Imagem" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-radius: 8px;">
```

To:

```
<img [src]="imgIdx.Imagem" style="height: 100%; width: auto; border-radius: 8px;">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but you still see the blue area (that is, it still doesn't occupy 100% of the area)